# Socket.io emit to specific client in tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io with angular. It works fine but my problem is that it emits to all the tabs opened in Chrome. The current workflow is the app will be opened in multiple tabs to run different simulation. When i press the button (action) it updates all the opened tabs. However, i want to emit to specific tab. How do i design that? I looked at stackoverflow and github but couldnt get the socket.id to work.

**Server Code**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var socketid = ''
    socketio.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socketid = socket.id

        res.socketid = socketid
            // 
    });
    res.socketio = socketio;
    next();
});

    console.log('sockrt ' + res.socketid)
    res.socketio.emit('pyr', output) //res.socketid is undefined
```

**Updated**

app.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var socketid = ''
    socketio.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socketid = socket.id

        res.socketid = socketid
            // 
    });
    res.socketio = socketio;
    next();
});
```

py.controller.js (api endpoint)

```
export function index(req, res) {
        console.log('sockrt ' + res.socketid)
        res.socketio.emit('pyr', output)

    };
```

The endpoint is working and socket.io is working but the socket.id is undefined. I just need to figure out a way to isolate the connection to a browser tab.

Comment: Where are you testing your res.socketid (i.e. where is that console.log statement located)?  There's a good chance that whats happening is you're accessing outside of where it gets set (within the socket connection event) before it even gets set, hence its undefined

Comment: As david said, since its async, socketid is not defined if it gets executed after.

Comment: @DavidTamrazov updated the code to explain.

Comment: Now, the socket.id has been resolved after i made socketio a global variable. However, whenever i open a new tab the socket.id is being  assigned to all new tabs. I am unable to isolate connections between open tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to solve this problem after some trial and error. Looking through SO, there were solutions based on express sessions shared between express and socket. While it worked, i was not able to isolate individual tabs. My use case is to set this as an app that can be used in multiple instances across browsers (think of it as quotation engine). The below solution worked for me.

**Server code**

```
  socketio.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.address = `${socket.request.connection.remoteAddress}:${socket.request.connection.remotePort}`;

    //  USED TO SET THE SOCKET ID FOR THE REQUEST
    socket.emit('initialize', socket.id)


    socket.connectedAt = new Date();
}
```

**Client Code**

 In Angular, i setup an initialize event to store the specific socket Id for the tab

```
    this.socket.on('initialize', socketid => {
        console.log(socketid)
        this.socketid = socketid
    })
```

When the request is sent to express, i send the socketid as a header

```
return this.$http({
    method: 'POST',
    withCredentials: true,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    data: sim_data,
    port: 3000,
    responseType: "arraybuffer",
    headers: {
        "X-socketid": this.socketid
    },
    url: '/api/blah'
})
```

**Server Code**

Finally, when express processes the POST or get i emit to the socketid from Header

```
    // GET SOCKET ID FROM HEADER
    var socket_id = req.headers['x-socketid']

    if (typeof socket_id !== 'undefined' && socket_id) {
        var io = req.app.get('io')
        io.sockets.connected[socket_id].emit('pyr', output)
    }
```

My next step is to integrate this with user authorization.